# Give members of dynamic distribution group full access to shared mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, microsoft, shared-mailbox

For one of our costumers I have created a new shared mailbox on their exchange server. The users that they want me to give full access are already filtered in a dynamic distribution group. I have tried to look up ways to add these members with full access to the new shared mailbox, but I can't find any powershell command or any information about a possible way to do this.

Exchange 2010/2013 server.

What I really wanted to do, but is not sure if it's even possible is to create a script for my exchange server/AD, to get the members from the dynamic group and add them to the new security group I have made for access to this mailbox. Preferably it would, when new users are created and added to the dynamic distribution group they would also automatically added to the security group in AD.

Is this at all possible?

Thank you for any help og suggestions!

Comment: How fit are you with powershell?

Comment: I work mainly with powershell in our systems. I'm still on an intermediate level, so I have the understanding and are able to write some scripts.

Comment: Here's a base script you could use: https://ravingroo.com/458/active-directory-shadow-group-automatically-add-ou-users-membership/
Instead of querying a OU you need to query the dynamic list. Let me know if you need help.